# declare varchar view issues

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the below code that I want to turn into a view.  However I cannot declare varchar in a view.

Can anyone advise on a way round this?

Sql Code -

```
DECLARE @PROJECTNUMBER VarChar
SELECT     SUM(PAFeeAmount) FeeAmount
FROM          PA02101
WHERE      PAPROJNUMBER = @PROJECTNUMBER
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can't do that inside a view, just make it without the `WHERE` clause then filter on the selection from the view: `SELECT * FROM Viewname where ...`.

Comment: Why would you want this in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an `inline table-valued` function. Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fxSample(@PROJECTNUMBER VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT  SUM(PAFeeAmount) FeeAmount
    FROM    PA02101
    WHERE   PAPROJNUMBER = @PROJECTNUMBER
)

-- Then call like this, just as if it's a table/view just with a parameter
SELECT * FROM dbo.fxSample('hello')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need variables, use a table-valued function instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to pass parameter(s) to a `VIEW`, you can't do that. Simply do your view as below using a Group By and filter during selection from the view.

```
CREATE VIEW myView
AS
   SELECT  PAPROJNUMBER, SUM(PAFeeAmount) FeeAmount
   FROM   PA02101
   GROUP BY PAPROJNUMBER


--Select like below. (may be passing it to a stored procedure)
declare @projectNumber varchar(50) --remember to give a length 

select * from myView
where projectNumber = @projectNumber
```